# Problems when calling PowerShell with instructions as parameters

Tags: windows, powershell, terminal, arguments, parameter-passing

I am writing a program that involves running PowerShell and passing the instructions as the first argument. I pass multiple instructions and chain them together with a `;`. After debugging and testing things I think I found the essence of my problem, and I honestly can't tell if this is a PowerShell glitch or if I'm just extremely dumb. The 'glitch' essentially boils down to the following:

If you open PowerShell and run:

```
$string = "test"; Add-Content "A:\file.txt" $string
```

You obtain a file.txt and it contains "test", as expected.
Now if you instead call PowerShell, say from the terminal, and pass this instruction as a parameter, you obtain file.txt but with no content inside, despite the command being identical. My guess is that the `$string` variable is discarded after the `;` when the instruction is passed as an argument, but what do I know. Could there be a work around, or am I missing something obvious?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
powershell $x="test"; add-content c:\path\test.txt $x
```

is treated something like

```
powershell 
    $x="test";        # run this script code

        add-content   # with this as parameter 1
        c:\sc\q.txt   # with this as parameter 2
        $x            # with this as parameter 3
```

You want to quote it so all of the script is a single argument to powershell.exe, something more like this:

```
powershell "$x='test'; add-content c:\path\test.txt $x"
```

Comment: Thank you so much, that was it! I was convinced I tried that and it didn't work, but I must have made a mistake then